# scalatra-swaggerで、sbtビルドする時にOpenAPIドキュメントをファイルに書き出したい

Tags: api, scala

今、ScalatraでRESTfulなAPIサーバを作成しています。
またこのAPIサーバは、swaggerを使ってAPIドキュメントを管理していきたいと思っています。
そこで scalatra-swagger を導入して、API管理を行うようにすることにしました。

しかし scalatra-swagger に関して調べきれた範囲では
OpenApiドキュメントを出力するエンドポイントをscalatraのAPIサーバ内部に作る
という利用方法だけが紹介されており、
OpenApiドキュメントをビルド時にファイルに出力する方法が見当たりません。

今回の場合、Swaggerはプロダクション環境にあるAPIサーバとは疎通させたくありません。
そのためできれば、このエンドポイントは作らずに、OpenApiドキュメントをビルドするたびに1度だけ生成し、
Swaggerの入った開発用のDockerコンテナなどに転送して利用したいのです。

そこでsbtビルドのときに1度だけ生成するような形にする方法があれば、教えていただけないでしょうか。
またはそういった使い方はできない場合は、そのことを教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現状ではScalatra-Swaggerには、そのような機能は無く、できないです
要望があればぜひGitHubのIssueに挙げてください

Comment: ありがとうございます。Issue作成かPRかをやってみます